# How can I group by month from a date field using Python and Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe, *df*, which is as follows:

```
| date      | Revenue |
|-----------|---------|
| 6/2/2017  | 100     |
| 5/23/2017 | 200     |
| 5/20/2017 | 300     |
| 6/22/2017 | 400     |
| 6/21/2017 | 500     |
```

I need to group the above data by month to get output as:

```
| date | SUM(Revenue) |
|------|--------------|
| May  | 500          |
| June | 1000         |
```

I tried this code, but it did not work:

```
df.groupby(month('date')).agg({'Revenue': 'sum'})
```

I want to only use Pandas or [NumPy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy) and no additional libraries.

Comment: `df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date',freq='M')).agg({'Revenue':'sum'})`, this assumes the data type of the date column is datetime

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Try this:

```
In [6]: df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

In [7]: df
Out[7]:
        date  Revenue
0 2017-06-02      100
1 2017-05-23      200
2 2017-05-20      300
3 2017-06-22      400
4 2017-06-21      500



In [59]: df.groupby(df['date'].dt.strftime('%B'))['Revenue'].sum().sort_values()
Out[59]:
date
May      500
June    1000
```

Comment: up vote because it's the only answer which formats the `date` column properly

Comment: FYI this gives u a string column for the date which is not as performant nor useful (as real resamplimg / time grouping)

Comment: @shivsn: can this be sorted by date- ascending wise (May-500 and then June -1000) ?

Comment: what do u mean by df. how to import df??

Comment: @Ragulan28 df is the name of the DateFrame.For eg df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')

Comment: I want to add 1 more groupby column in your solution how can I do that?like this lead_visits.groupby(['date', 'status'], as_index=False) but instead of 'date', I want months of all dates

Comment: Method 3 by @yongtw123 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50962588/10916136) is much faster.

Answer (score 34):

Try a groupby using a pandas [Grouper](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Grouper.html):

```python
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['6/2/2017','5/23/2017','5/20/2017','6/22/2017','6/21/2017'],'Revenue':[100,200,300,400,500]})
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
dg = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='1M')).sum() # groupby each 1 month
dg.index = dg.index.strftime('%B')
```

Output:

```
     Revenue
 May    500
June    1000
```

Comment: This seems to be the best combination between performance and general usability

Comment: this is the most usable since the months are aggregated in order. This should be the top answer.

Comment: This doesn't work if your dates are across years. Then instead of just one row for month (say May and June above), it will have multiple May's and June's for each year.

Comment: This answer is totally wrong. It groups by year month not month.

Answer (score 12):

For DataFrame with many rows, using `strftime` takes up more time. If the date column already has dtype of `datetime64[ns]` (can use `pd.to_datetime()` to convert, or specify `parse_dates` during csv import, etc.), one can directly access datetime property for `groupby` labels (Method 3). The speedup is substantial.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

T = pd.date_range(pd.Timestamp(0), pd.Timestamp.now()).to_frame(index=False)
T = pd.concat([T for i in range(1,10)])
T['revenue'] = pd.Series(np.random.randint(1000, size=T.shape[0]))
T.columns.values[0] = 'date'

print(T.shape) #(159336, 2)
print(T.dtypes) #date: datetime64[ns], revenue: int32
```

#### Method 1: strftime

```
%timeit -n 10 -r 7 T.groupby(T['date'].dt.strftime('%B'))['revenue'].sum()
```

1.47 s ± 10.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

#### Method 2: Grouper

```
%timeit -n 10 -r 7 T.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='1M')).sum()
#NOTE Manually map months as integer {01..12} to strings
```

56.9 ms ± 2.88 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

#### Method 3: datetime properties

```
%timeit -n 10 -r 7 T.groupby(T['date'].dt.month)['revenue'].sum()
#NOTE Manually map months as integer {01..12} to strings
```

34 ms ± 3.34 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

Comment: Note that if you have data from more than 1 year, methods 1 and 3 aggregate over them whereas method 2 does not. Also, the result from method 1 is sorted alphabetically.

Comment: how to arrange the outputs in ascending order? since it is now array not df

Answer (score 3):

This will work better.

Try this:

```
# Explicitly convert to date
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
# Set your date column as index 
df.set_index('Date',inplace=True) 

# For monthly use 'M', If needed for other freq you can change.
df[revenue].resample('M').sum()
```

This code gives the same result as [shivsn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44908383/how-can-i-group-by-month-from-a-date-field-using-python-and-pandas/44908600#44908600) on the first post.

But the thing is we can do a lot more operations in this mentioned code.

It is recommended to use this:

```
>>> df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
>>> df.set_index('Date',inplace=True)
>>> df['withdrawal'].resample('M').sum().sort_values()
Date
2019-10-31     28710.00
2019-04-30     31437.00
2019-07-31     39728.00
2019-11-30     40121.00
2019-05-31     46495.00
2020-02-29     57751.10
2019-12-31     72469.13
2020-01-31     76115.78
2019-06-30     76947.00
2019-09-30     79847.04
2020-03-31     97920.18
2019-08-31    205279.45
Name: withdrawal, dtype: float64
```

where [shivsn's code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44908383/how-can-i-group-by-month-from-a-date-field-using-python-and-pandas/44908600#44908600) does the same.

```
>>> df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.strftime('%B'))['withdrawal'].sum().sort_values()
Date
October       28710.00
April         31437.00
July          39728.00
November      40121.00
May           46495.00
February      57751.10
December      72469.13
January       76115.78
June          76947.00
September     79847.04
March         97920.18
August       205279.45
Name: withdrawal, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Why would you have to set the date as the `DataFrame` index when `groupby` works just fine? What happens if you have same date repeated? I would also consider the date formatting as first step, the highest voted answer, because it is not clear from the question if that column will be properly formatted.

Comment: Either it is a duplicate or unique , it is going to sum up all those values. It acts as same as groupby.And apart from groupby options , By setting the date column as index you can perform lot more basic operations. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Change the date column into datetime format.

   ---> `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])`
2. Insert a new row in the data frame which has month like [May, 'June']

   ---> `df['months'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x:x.strftime('%B'))`

   ---> here x is date which take from date column in data frame.
3. Now aggregate the aggregate data in the month column and sum the revenue.

   --->`response_data_frame = df.groupby('months')['Revenue'].sum()`

   ---->`print(response_data_frame)`

Output:

| month | Revenue |
| --- | --- |
| May | 500 |
| June | 1000 |

Answer (score 0):

```
df['Month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['date']).month_name()
```

Using this you should get

| date | Revenue | Month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6/2/2017 | 100 | June |
| 5/23/2017 | 200 | May |
| 5/20/2017 | 300 | May |
| 6/22/2017 | 400 | June |
| 6/21/2017 | 500 | June |